# Multiple inheritance pattern for vehicle information

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, inheritance

I wanted an easy way to augment objects, by adding functionality from any other object(s). More importantly, I needed a way to augment the object from multiple sources in a clean one-line solution.

The inheritance is done with this:

```
function extend(proto, args){
    this[proto.id] = Object.create(proto);
    proto.constructor.call(this[proto.id], args);
}

extend.call(this, vehicle, args); // one-liner
```

I can invoke as many objects as needed; with this pattern it's easy to swap and change the prototype chain, so I could just put the above extend code in the vehicle object, if that's where I want augmentation.

It's now easy to create a car by pulling in whatever you need:

> ```
> extend.call(this, vehicle, args);
> extend.call(this, sunroof, args);
> extend.call(this, tyres, args);
> extend.call(this, wings, args);
> extend.call(this, rocket, args);
> etc...
> ```

Questions:

- Plausibility: is it flawed in some way?
- Optimisation: can I enhance the pattern?
- clunky: I had to create an `id` property for each object, so the extend function knows how to create a property on the executing context. It seems like a hack. Is there a way to get a prototype name from a named constructor?

> ```
> var manufacturer = {
>     id:'manufacturer',
>     constructor : function (args) {
>         this.boss = args.boss || 'Bernie Ecclestone';
>       this.country = args.country || 'UK';    
>         return this;
>     }
> };
>
> var vehicle = {
>     id:'vehicle',
>     constructor : function (args) {
>         this.colour = args.colour || 'blue';
>       this.wheels = args.wheels || 2;     
>         extend.call(this, manufacturer, args);
>         return this;
>     }
> };
>
> var driver = {
>     id:'driver',
>     constructor : function (args) {
>         this.name = args.name || 'John';
>         return this;
>     },
>     info : function () { console.log(this.name); }
> };
>
> var engine = {
>     id:'engine',
>     constructor : function (args) {
>         this.type = args.type || 'V6';
>         this.fuel = args.fuel || 'petrol';
>         return this;
>     },
>     tune : function () { 
>         this.type = 'super-charged';
>         this.fuel = 'ethanol';
>         console.log('Car now ' + this.type + ' with ' + this.fuel); 
>     }
> };
>
> var car = {
>     id:'car',
>     constructor : function (args) {       
>         extend.call(this, vehicle, args);
>       extend.call(this, driver, args); 
>         extend.call(this, engine, args);   
>         return this;
>     },
>     info : function () { 
>         console.log('boss: ' + this.vehicle.manufacturer.boss);
>         console.log('country: ' + this.vehicle.manufacturer.country);
>         console.log('driver: ' + this.driver.name);
>         console.log('colour: ' + this.vehicle.colour);
>       console.log('wheels: ' + this.vehicle.wheels);
>       console.log('type: '   + this.engine.type);
>       console.log('fuel: '   + this.engine.fuel);
>         console.log('\n');
>   }
> };
>
> function extend(proto, args){
>   this[proto.id] = Object.create(proto);
>   proto.constructor.call(this[proto.id], args);
> }
>
> var ferrari = Object.create(car).constructor({
>     boss: 'Maurizio Arrivabene',
>     country:'Italy',
>     name: 'Steve', 
>     colour: 'red', 
>     wheels: 4, 
>     type:'100cc', 
>     fuel:'diesel'
> });
>
> var lotus = Object.create(car).constructor({
>     name: 'Jenson Button'
> });
>
> var mclaren = Object.create(car).constructor({
>   type:'hybrid',
>     fuel:'battery/petrol'
> });
>
> ferrari.engine.tune();
> ferrari.info();
> /*
> Car now super-charged with ethanol
> boss: Maurizio Arrivabene
> country: Italy
> driver: Steve
> colour: red
> wheels: 4
> type: super-charged
> fuel: ethanol
> */
>
> lotus.info();
> /*
> boss: Bernie Ecclestone
> country: UK
> driver: Jenson Button
> colour: blue
> wheels: 2
> type: V6
> fuel: petrol
> */
>
> mclaren.info();
> /*
> boss: Bernie Ecclestone
> country: UK
> driver: John
> colour: blue
> wheels: 2
> type: hybrid
> fuel: battery/petrol
> */
> ```

Comment: @Mat's Mug - someone answered, but it's disappeared; could you enlighten me please.

Comment: Why don't you use more common `function Foo() {}; Foo.prototype.bar = function() {}; var foo = new Foo();`?

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting concept, I could see this turning into a "Pimp my Ride" game. A few things before this is sent off to gamers:

### OOP

It seems like you've *kind of* misunderstood what OOP is about. As it is, you have a lot of *variables* (not objects) which then are smushed together into a final concept (the car).

If you want this to be more OOP oriented, here's some things I suggest:

Get rid of all the variables, except `car`. Keep this, as it will represent your "object". Instead of the manufacturer having his own variable (who knows, maybe some car will be custom built or have various manufacturers), use [getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) to define a *property* of car. Picture it this way:

```
Car object {
    Initialize the object here

    get manufacturer() {

    }
    set manufacturer(string or array or object) {

    }
}
```

Now your code might get a big here if you implement each detail with a getter and setter. Sometimes you can manage this, other times not, which then you might break things apart: have the manufacturer get/set in an engine object, and the car will only have the get/set for engines.

Like one of the comments said, you should [research object prototyping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype#Examples). For a fresh start on JavaScript programming in an object oriented style, [read Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

### Misc.

I'm not convinced having a `Ferrari` variable and a `lotus` variable are the best way to accomplish creating cars. I suggest a new object, maybe `CarColection` or `Garage` and create/retrieve/store/pimp your cars their. It will allow for later changes, or dynamic modification of the cars.

Purely for fun and for homework: add in the ability to specify exhaust, transmission, tires, driving skill, etc. and then compute horsepower/car level. Pretty soon you could challenge cars up against each other in races! :)